# Cordova fails on a fresh Mojave installation

Tags: google-maps, cordova, ionic-framework, cordova-plugins

I installed a fresh Mojave to find this error with my build and I am not sure how to debug this, seems it's coming out of

cordova-plugin-googlemaps/PluginLocationService.m

```
cordova run ios --debug --verbose

The following build commands failed:


CompileC /Users/me/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/app-bdpokdmgnlhxvrfpkwhgoykdgckc/Build/Intermediates.noindex/app.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/app.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/PluginCircle.o app/Plugins/cordova-plugin-googlemaps/PluginCircle.m normal x86_64 objective-c com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0.compiler

CompileC /Users/me/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/app-bdpokdmgnlhxvrfpkwhgoykdgckc/Build/Intermediates.noindex/app.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/app.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/PluginLocationService.o app/Plugins/cordova-plugin-googlemaps/PluginLocationService.m normal x86_64 objective-c com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0.compiler
(2 failures)
CordovaError: Promise rejected with non-error: 'Error code 65 for command: xcodebuild with args: -xcconfig,/Users/me/Documents/app/platforms/ios/cordova/build-debug.xcconfig,-workspace,app.xcworkspace,-scheme,app,-configuration,Debug,-sdk,iphonesimulator,-destination,platform=iOS Simulator,name=iPhone X,build,CONFIGURATION_BUILD_DIR=/Users/me/Documents/app/platforms/ios/build/emulator,SHARED_PRECOMPS_DIR=/Users/me/Documents/app/platforms/ios/build/sharedpch'


ionic info

Ionic:

   ionic (Ionic CLI)  : 4.10.3
   Ionic Framework    : ionic-angular 3.9.2
   @ionic/app-scripts : 3.2.0

Cordova:

   cordova (Cordova CLI) : 8.1.2 (cordova-lib@8.1.1)
   Cordova Platforms     : ios 4.5.5
   Cordova Plugins       : cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard 2.1.3, cordova-plugin-ionic-webview 1.2.1, (and 9 other plugins)

System:

   NodeJS : v11.10.0 (/Users/me/.nvm/versions/node/v11.10.0/bin/node)
   npm    : 6.7.0
   OS     : macOS Mojave
   Xcode  : Xcode 10.1 Build version 10B61
```

Answer (score 0):

Solution - install missing CocoaPods

```
cd platform/ios
pod install
```